# Method returning different types usage

Tags: javascript, typescript

If method returns several differently structured objects typescript argues that there could be no property x in resulting object. How to notify typescript compiler that in this call method will always return object with X property.

[Link to the playground containing the same code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUYoBXbGUqYADTgG8AoOOEALjiVIFsAjNRgF9GjUJFiIUaLLgLEyFKsACaDZnACeHLnwHDG2CEgDO8UwsrU6AXgbs4ARmGGTZkuUsq4t%20lsf6AG2AzYCCKYAATeQ8lDiJ3RSs4AB85BM9lETFoeHRSJAoEIzhjUOAKaMTaOAAKAEoOADcIBAi1FlKw1Cj0pW8S3qshLPAcuDyCmCKkErKKwa96ppa2pg657srPfvMY6kz9AHoAKjhmU6QIODBMKExuYLRjOAALNDwamDeS%207wHr4gbWwmACAUks0aaBB1wCOGAz2olhMZzgpwiCHQ6HeKAGFiUzwiwDAwCQ6KQAHM4MUAO4vBDYF5wamYZ6dcrdOrnQ6iUYSCaFYrk4KEDaRLZ9JZpPFJVLxaVeNaIqgzNnhHry4aMVUwcVWeoGIymODcDS62hxM02OBCnWi9V7YD6w6HOAuI0my0cTBIDT9G0irpihZOl1u%20AehY0C2Rv3Cu1m%20pwFlSh00EQY2oR%20U0AB0IDq7VdhogQRzAQg5JqAHJqNC5amqbwAFbsgA0cAiV2MEH%20dIpVc5gjgoVKhbdJeAZYr1c7nAgX2Q5IHmpEQA)

```
export interface IStructureX {
  x: number
}

export interface IStructureY {
  y: number
}

const structureX = {x: 1}
const structureY = {y: 1}

let selectedStructure: IStructureX | IStructureY

export function selectStructureX (): void {
  selectedStructure = structureX
}

export function selectStructureY (): void {
  selectedStructure = structureY
}

/* 
 * no parameters here (the same method call in several places returns 
 * different structures depending on which was selected)
 */
export function getSelectedStructure (): IStructureX | IStructureY {
 return selectedStructure
}

selectStructureX()
const myStructureX: IStructureX = getSelectedStructure()
// const myStructureX: any = getSelectedStructure()
// const myStructureX: IStructureX = getSelectedStructure() as IStructureX

if (myStructureX.x) {
  console.log('real IStructureX object, do something')
} else {
  console.log('do nothing')
}
```

Dont want to add `:any` on const `myStructureX: IStructureX` instead of real type that must be there.

Comment: Can you update your code example to be compiling TypeScript? You're missing a couple of required keywords and referencing a function not present (`getStructure()`).

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/8w8r4m) where the only issue present is the one you're asking about.  This will help others start from your problem and work on a solution, instead of having them first work on getting to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some possible solutions could be:

1. Using a common structure

```
export interface ICommonStructure {
    [key: string]: number;
}
```

With this you can use `{x: 5}` and `{y: 3}` and `{x: 3, y:5}`, or whatever you want without problems. For example, if you have more complex objects that differs solely on some key you can do:

```
export interface IStructure {
    commonKey1: string,
    commonKey2: string;
    commonKey3: number;
    [otherKey: string]: any;
}
```

2. using `as`: if you already know that you will work with IStructure[X/Y], you can do:

```
const myStructureX: IStructureX = getSelectedStructure() as IStructureX
```

or, shorter:

```
const myStructureX = getSelectedStructure() as IStructureX
```